# HTML5 Canvas Clip or Crop Everything but an S shape

Tags: html, canvas

How would I clip everything in the following drawing except for the S stroke? In other words get rid of all transparent space and only keep black S shape... thanks in advance!

=== PNG RENDERED IMAGE OF CANVAS ===
image located at --> http://buildasearch.com/ant/s.png

=== ACTUAL COORDINATES OF CANVAS DRAWING ===

```
var x =  '68,67,66,65,64,63,62,61,60,59,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,52,55,56,52,58,60,59,61,62,64,65,66,68,70,71,72,74,75,76,77,78,78,79,79,79,79,79,79,79,79,79,79,79,79,78,76,74,71,67,59,56,54,52,49,47,46,45,43,42,41,40,39';

var y = '11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,13,14,14,15,17,18,20,21,23,24,27,30,32,32,34,34,33,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,37,38,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,59,59,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60';
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The hosted s.png image has alot of whitespace but want to get rid of it, i was thinking clipping everything in the canvas but the S shape coordinates... not sure if that is possible.  kinda like the magic wand in photoshop....

Comment: I think I understand you now. You want to auto-crop the image. Are you wanting to do this when producing PNG output with e.g. `canvas.toDataURL`, or do you want to statically analyse the data you've given above to work out what will be the dimensions, and resize the canvas, before drawing it?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if your `x` and `y` were of the form `[6, 3, 19]` instead of `'6,3,19'`. For the purposes of this answer, I will assume that you have it done this way as it makes the code a bit easier.

It's quite possible to calculate afterwards, but it would get messy with getting the bit that you want and then resizing the canvas. It will end up easier and faster to calculate it before-hand if you can. Something like this should work:

```
// Data specification
var x = [68,67,66,65,64,63,62,61,60,59,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,51,51,51,51,51,51,52,55,56,52,58,60,59,61,62,64,65,66,68,70,71,72,74,75,76,77,78,78,79,79,79,79,79,79,79,79,79,79,79,79,78,76,74,71,67,59,56,54,52,49,47,46,45,43,42,41,40,39],
    y = [11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,13,14,14,15,17,18,20,21,23,24,27,30,32,32,34,34,33,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,37,38,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,59,59,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60];

// Work out the extreme points in both dimensions
var xs = x.slice().sort(),
    ys = y.slice().sort(),
    minX = xs[0],
    maxX = xs[xs.length-1],
    minY = ys[0],
    maxY = ys[ys.length-1];
// Resize the canvas
canvas.width = maxX - minX + 1;
canvas.height = maxY - minY + 1;
// Shift the points to fit on the shrunk canvas
x.forEach(function(v, i) {
    x[i] = v - minX;
});
y.forEach(function(v, i) {
    y[i] = v - minY;
});
```